# Is there a way to tell if the RouterModule useHash in Angular 8 is set to true?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, hash-location-strategy

I'm working on a library for my job that allows other development teams to use some of our Angular components and pass in there own configurations. One of the is the is the RouterModule.

I've found some code in our library where I need to determine if they have enabled he `useHash: true` parameter in the configuration for the Module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

All I need to do really is see if it's been set to true or is false or null but I've been combing through the docs and searching Google and I'm stumped.

I tried something simple but of course this does not work.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private module: RouterModule) {
   console.log(router.useHash)
}
```

Does anyone know of this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer comes late but may still be useful to someone.

```
constructor(private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
}

useHash() {
  return this.platformLocation.hash?.indexOf('#') > -1;
}
```